# App Store Connect Metadata rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I got this error for my game on the app store, I'm not fully sure what it's really telling me to fix... has anyone else had this rejection? Thank you!

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> This type of app has been identified as one that may violate one or
>   more of the following App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, these
>   types of apps often:
>
> 1.1.6 - Include false information, features, or misleading metadata.
>   2.3.0 - Undergo significant concept changes after approval
>   2.3.1 - Have hidden or undocumented features, including hidden "switches" that redirect to a gambling or lottery website
>   3.1.1 - Use payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase to unlock features or functionality in the app
>   3.2.1 - Do not come from the financial institution performing the loan services
>   4.3.0 - Are a duplicate of another app or are conspicuously similar to another app
>   5.2.1 - Were not submitted by the legal entity that owns and is responsible for offering any services provided by the app
>   5.2.3 - Facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media from third party sources without
>   explicit authorization from those sources
>   5.3.4 - Do not have the necessary licensing and permissions for all the locations where the app is used
>
> Before we can continue with our review, please confirm that this app
>   does not violate any of the above guidelines. You may reply to this
>   message in Resolution Center or the App Review Information section in
>   App Store Connect to verify this app’s compliance.
>
> Given the tendency for apps of this type to violate the aforementioned
>   guidelines, this review will take additional time. If at any time we
>   discover that this app is in violation of these guidelines, the app
>   will be rejected and removed from the App Store, and it may result in
>   the termination of your Apple Developer Program account.
>
> Should you choose to resubmit this app without confirming this app’s
>   compliance, the next submission of this app will still require a
>   longer review time. Additionally, this app will not be eligible for an
>   expedited review until we have received your confirmation.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT
>   require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect
>   to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve
>   completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and
>   we will continue the review.

Comment: You need to verify if your app met all the guidelines mentioned above and if not you need to update your metadata and re submit for the review. For example : If the app qualifies as a gambling app, you need to demonstrate related gaming licensing.

Comment: How do I exactly verify that my app has all the guidelines mentioned? Do I just type it in the box they provided?

Comment: Yes, reply them through the resolution center and then they will resume the review process.

Comment: I have the same issue. I replied that my app does not violate any guidelines. I am still waiting for their response. Did they response to you?

Comment: @KelvinTan been 2 days and haven't heard anything yet. Hoping its soon :)

Comment: @BrendonSon Do you have any updates about your case? I'm facing the same issue here.